# Ubuntu 18.04 Delete Software

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I tried several ways to completely delete the Atom from my computer.  But after that, I got this icon 
[image: Screenshot].

I still can open Atom but my package all gone. If I am not wrong this is a snap of atom, right? I ran *which atom* command to find the direction. I got *snap/bin*. But I can not find it. How can I completely delete it?

Comment: hi Yuan Gao. Welcome to  Stack Overflow. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on topic for [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043199/uninstall-atom-on-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: What were the several ways you tried to delete it, and what happened? How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: @Xen2050 I tried sudo apt-get remove atom, dpkg -l |grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}' |xargs apt -y purge and delete .atom folder from directory. I install atom 2 times. One is from the official website, another one is from ubuntu software. I think is because I didn't delete snap. The link from previous comment works. But I have other software have the same icon as atom. I can't use the same way to remove it.

Comment: Possibly the icon & entry in the screenshot is just a leftover in the menu, if the atom (or other) software is already gone then just editing the menu & deleting that entry would work. (I'm not exactly sure how to do that for your Ubuntu though, I'd search for your desktop type (like Gnome 3 or Unity or whichever it is) and "edit menu" or similar)